# Getting argparse documentation as string

Tags: python, argparse, ipython-magic

I am using argparse to create an ipython magic. The library is nicely printing some documentation when calling `parser.print_doc()`. However, is there a way to get the documentation as a string instead, so that I can attach it to `__doc__` of my ipython cell?

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
@magics_class
class MagicClass(Magics):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Some description.')
    parser.add_argument('foo', nargs='*', help='Foo variables.')
    […]
    def __init__(self):
        # attach the doc from the parser to the __doc__ object of the
        # class
        self.__doc__.append(parser.get_help_as_string())
        […]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`format_help()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.format_help) method.